# Stored procedure on the SqlDataSource is not working with single quotation inside SelectCommand with single quotation C# asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I am in trouble right now regarding on how to make my stored procedure work inside a `SqlDataSource` on aspx page.

This is my markup:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSourceGrantInfo" runat="server" 
     ConnectionString="<%# _connection.strConnectionString %>"
     SelectCommand='<%# "EXEC dbo._GetCurrentSession " + Eval("Film_strCode") + " " %>' />
```

The above code is working fine though without single quotation in it. But when I tried to put a single quotation, It doesn't work. There will be an error on the tag.

See this markup :

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSourceGrantInfo" runat="server" 
     ConnectionString="<%# _connection.strConnectionString %>"
     SelectCommand='<%# "EXEC dbo._GetCurrentSession 'some_value_here' " %>' />
```

Please help me to know why stored procedure with single quotation does not work on aspx page? I need to make my code like this with single quotation but it doesn't work.

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSourceGrantInfo" runat="server" 
     ConnectionString="<%# _connection.strConnectionString %>"
     SelectCommand='<%# "EXEC dbo._GetCurrentSession '" + Eval("Film_strCode") + "'" %>' />
```

Are there any way to make it work? Please help me.

Comment: try \' instead of single quote (')

Comment: If your first code snippet works, then why change it at all?

Comment: @JennyO'Reilly - because I set my parameter at stored procedure as string. The stored procedue must have a single quotation (') . The code works fine without single quotation but it does't return any data since the parameter on my stored procedure is string.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to use a stored procedure from your `SqlDataSource`, you should use this approach - defining the command type to be `StoredProcedure`, and setting the parameters properly:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSourceGrantInfo" runat="server" 
     ConnectionString="<%# _connection.strConnectionString %>"
     SelectCommand="dbo._GetCurrentSession"
     SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="SessionValue" Type="Int32" DefaultValue="0" />
    </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```